# Excel data table with key auto-increment

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a table with each row indexed by auto-increment.

I tried using `A2=A1+1` or adding 1 to the previous value. This should be the solution according to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/130274/autonumbering-a-column-in-excel). However adding new rows (using the tab key or dragging the corner down) doesn't automatically increment the index column.

What's the solution?

Comment: Assuming you have a header row, which a table requires, then A2 would contain the initial value, and A3 would contain the formula =A2+1. As long as your table is formatted as such, then that formula should automatically be added whenever you add a row or rows. You might also try the formula =ROW()+1.

Comment: Sorry, that formula should have been =ROW()-1.

Comment: That's what I would expect too, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Try highlighting as many rows as you need to insert and then use the Insert command on the Home ribbon in the Cells box. That code actually works differently than the insert command using a right click of the mouse. I say this because when I use the right-click method and have complicated borders, the insert command from the Home ribbon duplicates the borders, but a right-click totally messes them up.  And I have the formula =ROW()-2 in my auto-increment column (I have two header rows).

Comment: Nope, it inserts blank cells too.

Comment: In your original post you mentioned a "table." Does this mean your spreadsheet is formatted as a table, or did you use the word generically? I ask because when you insert a row in an actual Excel table, Excel copies all the column formulas.

Comment: I mean a table object within the sheet

Answer (score 9):

If you reference `=row(1:1)` in the first row of your table, it will automatically fill in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. for as many rows as you have in your table.  The formula will automatically generate to be `=row(1:1)` or 1, `=row(2:2)` or 2, `=row(3:3)` or 3, etc.

I use this to create a unique key in a table for table values.

Comment: This assumes that the table will never be sorted. The column will always increment by 1, even if you sort it by largest to smallest.

Comment: Incrementing by pressing tab works fine but unfortunately inserting a row with right click menu doesn't

Answer (score 5):

Assume you want the ID to appear on Sheet1 Column A.

- Create a single cell Named Range, named `nmID` and paste formula `=MAX(Sheet1!A:A)+1`
- Select the cells on Sheet1 Column A that have values in that row.
- Click the Data Ribbon > Data Validation.
- Select `List` under Allow
- For Source type in `=nmID`

This will create a drop down list in column A that will should give you the next sequential number. The benefit to this approach is that the number stays the same even if you sort your data.

Comment: Paul, this works but I don't understand why. Can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: this is amazing! thank you @Pacul Gonley

HackSlash ... basically the formula says "give me the max value in the range and add 1" and then the column validation says, "the only valid value is whatever is in the cell which was just calculated."

Comment: @eusataf, you are the the question asker. I am not the one who wrote the answer. I only formatted the answer to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Paul Gonley I can't implement your solution. Could you please attach a drawing. What am I doing wrong? Picture https://ibb.co/PtZRVPc

Comment: @HackSlash Sorry. I deleted the comment that addressed you.
I think you should delete your comment.

Comment: @HackSlash Maybe you understand how it works?

Comment: Does anyone know if this works at all? I tried it but with no luck.